# Vertical text alignment between TikZ nodes with multiple lines of text

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I have three nodes of equal size which contain text of different lengths. This causes line breaks in two of the nodes.

I would like all of the text to be aligned with the last line of text in the third node. I have fiddled with text depth but because LaTeX reads the text in the third node as one line I don't think it's working the way I want it to.

Is there a simple solution to this problem? Any guidance is appreciated!

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node [draw, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em, align = center] (node1) {One line};    
  \node [draw, right = 1cm of node1, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em, align = center] (node2) {One linebreak};
  \node [draw, right = 1cm of node2, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em, align = center] (node3) {This text has two linebreaks};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the text separately from the boxes:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node [draw, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em] (node1) {};
  \node [draw, right = 1cm of node1, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em] (node2) {};
  \node [draw, right = 1cm of node2, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em] (node3) {};
  \node[text width=5em, align=center] (node3text) at (node3.center) {This text has two linebreaks};
  \node[anchor=south, text width=5em, align=center] at (node3text.south -| node2.center) {One linebreak};
  \node[anchor=south, text width=5em, align=center] at (node3text.south -| node1.center) {One line};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great (especially after I added \strut and \vphantom to my actual text to make sure all of the lines were even). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is ad hoc solution. If you can approximate the height of the highest text, you can use a proper `\vbox`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}



  \node [draw, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em, align = center] (node1) {\vbox to 3em{\vfill  One line}};    
  \node [draw, right = 1cm of node1, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em, align = center] (node2) {\vbox to 3em{\vfill One linebreak}};
  \node [draw, right = 1cm of node2, text width=5em, minimum height = 5em, align = center] (node3) {\vbox to 3em{\vfill This text has two linebreaks}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `equal height group` of `tcolorboxes` and define a `bottom` vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colback=white, sharp corners, width=2.5cm, equal height group=AT, before=, after=\hfill, notitle, halign=center, valign=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
One line
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
One\\ linebreak
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
This text\\ has two\\ linebreaks\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

After two compilations the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! Unfortunately I have to do this within a TikZ image.